# Performing simple custom operations with Einsum

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum, einops

I am new to `Einsum` and wanted a particular case - using `einsum` for multiplying all elements of a matrix with each other; say given a `2D` matrix:-

```py
np.random.rand((16,2))
```

Multiplying elements across an axis obtaining `(16,)` and then multiplying those with each other again to obtain `(1,)` a scalar. This is something like:-

```py
[[1, 2],  ==> [2, 12] ==> 24
 [3, 4]]
```

I tried using stuff like:-

```py
...("ij->")
```

But that's definitely not what I want, as its not **multiplication**

How can we write such simple operations with `einsum`? can einsum not handle every single operation, but is optimized for a few hard cases?

Comment: `einsum` is primarily a matrix multiplication tool.  That is, it performs the typical `sum-of-products`, with a lot of control over which axes are summed and which pass through.  It is not a general purpose multiplier.  It can sum within one array, but the multiplication is between arrays.

Comment: 'ij->i' is a summation over the `j`, 2nd axis.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what your goal is here. If we had the example matrix [[1,2],[3,4]], then what should the result of this operation be?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Something like, `[[1*2],[3*4]]` ==> `[[2],[12]]` ==> `12*2 = 24` Which would be the final result - just multiplication instead of addition. I have edited my question to include the same

Comment: As mentioned above `einsum` performs *sum-of-producs*. If I understood you correctly a simple `.prod()` operation on the numpy array would do the job. The order of the axis doesn't even matter here.

Comment: Indeed, I agree its a much simpler and readable way; however, the entire point of this post was do arbitrary ops with `einsum` instead since I would love to gain a mastery of it for future use. I was surprised that there is no way to accomplish this - so perhaps `einsum` is not as versatile a tool as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
einops.reduce(x, 'i j -> i', 'prod')
```

should do the trick for you.

As @neel-g pointed, einsum is sum-of-products by definition.

Comment: that's brilliant - is there some detailed documentation (apart from the repo) that explains all these ops in-depth? because I don't see any good resources (like a cheatsheet) for beginners to start adopting einops :) and posting a S.O question every time I want to accomplish something seems like a bad idea

Comment: I think tutorial in the repository is a way to start. 
No, there is no cheatsheet AFAIK.